# Comparing 2 lists without using "in"

Tags: python

I am having trouble checking to see if a number from list1 is in list2 without using the word "in" in my if statements. Also, I am only able to use the functions len() and range()

Comment: So what have you tried so far?

Comment: Also this looks like a homework and this is not your homework solving forum.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [what you have tried so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include a [mcve] of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: what kind of sadistic homework is this ... what do you mean you can only use functions len and range?(clearly the author of this homework doesnt understand that its impossible to just use those 2 functions ... to solve this problem  (surely you also use something like `__getattr__` :P)

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop

Comment: http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>>l1 = [i for i in range(1,25)]
>>>l2 = [i for i in range(24, 50)]
>>>[x for x in l1 if x in l2]
[24]
```

Sorry I misread. How about this:

```
for i in range(len(l1)):
    for j in range(len(l2)):
        if l2[j] == l1[i]:
            print l2[j]
```

If you need to add matches to a list just create a list outside of the loop and append.